# How do I make a search that searches between two dates in ruby rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

Okay so I need to make a search that is set up something like:

From: (Search Field)  To: (Search Field)

and it only needs to show the dates equal to or in-between those fields.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is written in [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions), para 2.2.1:

```
Client.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date", {:start_date => params[:start_date], :end_date => params[:end_date]})
```

Comment: what would I need to put in my view for this action. It needs to be like a dropdown calendar?

Comment: also I got this error undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x249d35dc>

Comment: Replace the params with your actual field names

Answer (score 0):

You can write condition like below,

User.where("created_at >= ? and end_date <= ?",from_date, end_date),where
from_date,end_date --> are your required from_date and end_date stored in variables

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use range for this kind of search. For example:

`User.where(registred_at: from_field..to_field)`

Answer (score 0):

First set your params in form_tag search

```
= form_tag foo_path(@foo), :method => :get do
  = text_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date]
  = text_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date]
  = submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

and a most important is setting your definition your params in controller, if your search are in index than

```
def index
  @foos = Foo.all
  if params[:start_date].present?
    start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
    @foos = @foos.where("foo.foo_date >= ?", start_date)
  end
  if params[:end_date].present?
    start_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
    @foos = @foos.where("foo.foo_date >= ?", end_date)
  end
end
```